# OS X command to make current terminal window full screen

Tags: macos, bash, terminal.app, fullscreen, automator

I am trying to make a bash script to open up my working environment. I want

1) Open up Terminal.app and type a command like "time_to_work"
2) This command will:

a. open up sublime text

```
open ~/Documents/Programming/ -a Sublime\ Text.app
```

b. make the current terminal window full screen

c. Open up google chrome

I am getting stuck on 2.b. Is there a simple command, or would I have to do something like find the process ID and send it a signal (if that even makes sense)?

I would also be able to work with a command that will open up a new window in full screen mode.

Thanks!

Comment: What terminal application do you use?

Comment: The default one that comes pre-installed. Version 2.4

Comment: That's not Unix, that's Mac OS X (which technically is Unix-certified, but you couldn't achieve what  you want using the Unix subset of OS X)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use AppleScript commands:

```
osascript <<"EOF"
    tell application "Terminal" to activate
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "f" using { command down, control down }
    delay 3
    tell application "Google Chrome" to activate
EOF
```

The delay is necessary in order to have Terminal complete the fullscreen action.

Answer (score 0):

set MyApps to {"Google Chrome", "Skype", "Finder"}

repeat with MyApp in MyApps

```
tell application MyApp

    activate

    delay 3

end tell

tell application "System Events"

    tell process MyApp

        set value of attribute "AXFullScreen" of window 1 to true

        delay 3

    end tell

end tell
```

end repeat